Any reason the site starts to talk in Russian to me?
Today, I had the message in my inbox that I've earned a new privilege. The message was followed by "Узнайте больше об этом в Справке.", which LibreTranslate translates to "Find out more about this in the Help."

To my best knowledge, I never stated to speak Russian anywhere, and I can't find a language setting in my profile.

That must be a bug; I've put the [meta-tag:status-review] tag on it to escalate it to those who can deal with such things. (Sometimes the whole list of SE sites has an off-by-one error in correspondences; maybe [scifi.se] is alphabetically adjacent to [ru.so] or something?)

I spotted something similar the other day. I thought it might be because I had a VPN on

This is a known issue that's been happening sporadically for years: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522/461068

I'm going to go with "nyet"

Firstly, congrats on being able to create tag synonyms! And thanks for the report! I've fixed this to correctly provide per site translations for the privilege help text.
The explanation is basically the same as past incarnations of this issue where we've had a "first hit; first cached" issue. The simple version of the fix is to just do the localization each time and never store the result. With something like this change:
- public static string Message = Localize("Learn more about it in the help center");
+ public static string Message => Localize("Learn more about it in the help center");

But we also still want to cache it, so I put in a PerLocaleDictionary (custom wrapper we use to store caches per site local).  Issue should be all set in production.
See Also: Wrong language in recent achievements

Спасибо!​ ​ ​ ​

Пожалуйста!​ ​ ​

Without knowing the code base in any detail, that sounds like a sensible solution to me. Thanks for the fix, and thanks for the explanation.
